# .Net Core Configure Service with Database

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

I have a working site right now.
But ı have to make some changes on site system.
Now  i read stripe settings from appsetting.json and configure

```
services.Configure<StripeSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe"));
```

But i have to move this settings to my database and read it from there.
 How can i configure this setting from database in startup.cs.
 I can get my data from db but this methods require IConfiguration object.
How do i convert that.
Thanks.

Comment: Check [this example](https://codeburst.io/create-a-custom-configuration-provider-in-asp-net-core-cdd6a32b8ecb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with this piece of code if anyone need.

```
  services.Configure<StripeSettings>(opt => {
                    opt.PublishableKey = "value1";
                    opt.SecretKey = "value2";
                });
```